# World relief map, but only of the landforms

Tags: geographics

I want to create a map of the world's terrain (i.e. using `GeoStyling["ReliefMap"]`), but one that only shows the relief on the land, and not in the oceans (i.e. excluding submarine ridges, etc). Is there a way to restrict `GeoGraphics` to show only land relief, and display the seas and oceans as e.g. a neutral grey? Ideally, the coastlines would be outlined with a black line, but not also showing national borders (which `Polygon[Entity["Country", "World"]], EdgeForm[Black]` seems to force).

Can anyone help with this please? Apologies if this is answered elsewhere - I can't find anything similar with searches.

Answer (score 5):

One way:

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling["ReliefMap"], Polygon[Entity["Country", "World"]], 
             Polygon[Entity["GeographicRegion", "Antarctica"]]}, 
            GeoBackground -> GeoStyling[{"Coastlines", "Ocean" -> LightGray,
                                         "Border" -> Directive[Black, Thick]}],
            GeoRange -> "World"]
```

[image: relief map of world's land]

Comment: Thank you very much J.M!

Comment: Is there also a way to overlay selected rivers as black lines onto the ReliefMap?

Comment: That should probably be [a separate question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Thank you. I have done so at:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/159587/drawing-courses-of-rivers-on-a-geographics-reliefmap