# Drawing courses of rivers on a GeoGraphics ReliefMap

Tags: geographics

Is there a way to overlay selected rivers as black lines onto a GeoGraphics ReliefMap?

Comment: Start by doing a free-form search to find the relevant entities, then use the `Properties` property to see what kind of information you can get. I tried to search for "rivers in Sweden" and got only four, so the database of rivers is not that well developed. There doesn't seem to be a "coordinates" property for rivers, so that makes it impossible to map their paths. Also, the "source coordinates" and "outflow coordinates" properties were missing for the river that I tried it with, so I could not even draw a line between the start and the end.

Comment: Hmmm, that's what I had thought from interrogating the Entity properties for a few different rivers. Ok, thanks very much for checking for me - greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has to do with finding a data source (it turns out that the data is not in Mathematica) rather than Mathematica itself.